# Is $1+T$ a topological generator for $Z_{p}[[T]]$?

Tags: number-theory, topological-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Is $1+T$ a topological generator for $Z_{p}[[T]]$? ($Z_p$ is the ring of *p*-adic integers)

Comment: What constant terms do elements in the subring generated by that element have?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I felt like trying my hand at the problem and got that it is a topological generator. Based on your comment though you are implying it isn't. Can you check my argument below?

Comment: I’m not sure that I know what a topological generator is. Do you mean that the ring generated over $\Bbb Z_p$ by $1+T$ has for its closure the whole ring? If so, this is obviously true. Or do you mean the smallest closed subring of $\Bbb Z_p[[T]]$ that contains all powers of $1+T$ (not necessarily a $\Bbb Z_p$-algebra)?

Comment: @[tag:Lubin] Even I'm not sure what I meant. I was reading Coates-Sujatha's book cycolotmic fields. After Mahler's transform from $\Lambda[Z_{p}]$ to $Z_{p}[[T]]$ is defined a remark is made that for every topological generator $\gamma$ of $Z_{p}$ there is a unique topological isomorphism of $Z_{p}$ algebras which maps $\gamma$ to $1+T$. How should one interpret this?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with topological generators in a ring setting. I assume one wants the closure of the subring generated by an element to be the whole topological ring. We should have

$$\begin{array}{ll} \overline{\langle 1+T\rangle} & =\overline{(1+T)\Bbb Z[1+T]} \\ & =\overline{(1+T)\Bbb Z[T]} \\ & =(1+T)\overline{\Bbb Z[T]} \\ & =(1+T)\Bbb Z_p[[T]] \\ & =\Bbb Z_p[[T]] \end{array} $$

because $1+T\in\Bbb Z_p[[T]]^\times$ (whose inverse is provided by the geometric sum formula).

Comment: @[tag:whacka] Your argument seems to work, but I would like to remark that in the very first step the subring generated by $1+T$ is actually entire $Z[T+1]$ and hence $Z[T]$ and not just the ideal generated by $1+T$. Though I haven't checked if their closures are the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni2 I didn't know if we were to look at the unital subring or nonunital subring that it generated. I decided to get the stronger result because it wasn't much more work.

Comment: @SameerKulkarni2: To add to what whacka said, I would assume from the statement of the problem that you are asking about the nonunital subring, as otherwise it seems strange that you ask about $1+T$ rather than just $T$ (which obviously generates the same unital subring and would seem to be easier to think about).